# How can I use async with Map, in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I've tried iterating through a Map object using caolan/async, but I can't seem to find any simple way of doing it. Can you think of a simple solution, not involving storing all the keys and iterating through them? Something along the lines of :

```html
var async = require('async');
var m = new Map();
m.set("a", 1);
m.set("b", 2);

async.each(m.entries(), function(value, cb){
    console.info(value);
    cb();
}, function(){
    console.info("done");
})
```

I would use a `for(var entry of m.entries())` but I'm not sure this would be a good solution if instead of a simple log, I would do some IO operation.

Comment: Why would you need to use `async`? Just use a simple `for..of` loop.

Comment: what you want to do with map entries ? basically what is the use case, if you do not want to iterate ?

Comment: Some of the entries might cause an IO operation that would take a while, and others might be ignored. After all the entries have been processed, I need to make a final action, and `async` seems to provide everything I needed, if it could be used as with an array instead of a Map